# If $X \subseteq G$ is set of all pairwise commutative elements of $G$, prove that $\langle X \rangle \leqslant G$ abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I am trying to prove that if $X$ is a set of elements of a group $G$ such that each pair of elements of $X$ commute, then the subgroup $\langle X \rangle \leqslant G$ generated by $X$ is abelian.

**FYI: I have not learned what a center or a centralizer is yet; therefore, I cannot use either of those things in my proof.**

My attempt so far has been the following:

> Let $X \subseteq G$ s.t. $\forall a, b \in X$, $ab=ba$.
>
> Now, the subgroup $\langle X \rangle$ is the unique minimal subgroup of $G$ containing all elements of $X$.
>
> So, if $a,b \in X \cap \langle X \rangle$, there is nothing to prove.

My idea then was to take $c \in \langle X \rangle$ but not in $X$, and so $\forall a \in \langle X \rangle$, $ca \neq ac$, and derive some kind of contradiction from that. The same thing for the case where both $c, d \in \langle X \rangle$ but not in $X$. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do that.

Could somebody please tell me how I should prove this (not involving centralizers, centers, etc.)?

Comment: "So if $a,b\in X\cap\langle X\rangle$, there is nothing to prove." Yes there is. You still need to prove the rest of the pairs of elements in $\langle X\rangle $ commute! Do you know of any description of what the elements of $\langle X\rangle$ look like?

Comment: @arctictern, nope. $X$ is an arbitrary subset, so I have no idea what the elements of $\langle X \rangle$ look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I.** If $x\in G$ then $\{g\in G:xg=gx\}$ is a subgroup of $G.$

Proof. $$xe=x=ex;$$
$$xg_1=g_1x,\ xg_2=g_2x\implies xg_1g_2=g_1xg_2=g_1g_2x;$$
$$xg=gx\implies xg^{-1}=g^{-1}gxg^{-1}=g^{-1}xgg^{-1}=g^{-1}x.$$

**II.** If $x\in X,$ every element of $\langle X\rangle$ commutes with $x.$

Proof. Supose $x\in X.$ Then $H=\{g\in G:xg=gx\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ which contains $X.$ Since $\langle X\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $X,$ it follows that $\langle X\rangle\subseteq H,$ i.e., every element of $\langle X\rangle$ commutes with $x.$

**III.** If $a,b\in\langle X\rangle,$ then $ab=ba.$

Proof. Suppose $a,b\in\langle X\rangle.$ Let $J=\{g\in X:ag=ga\}.$ Since $J$ is a subgroup of $G$ which contains $X,$ we have $\langle X\rangle\subseteq J.$ Since $b\in\langle X\rangle,$ it follows that $b\in J,$ ie., $ab=ba.$

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm very tired. Would you mind explaining to me how we know that both $H$ and $J$ contain $X$? For some reason, it's not registering in my extremely fatigued brain.

Comment: I defined $H$ to be the set of all elements in $G$ that commute with $x.$ Since we assumed that all elements of $X$ commute with each other, and since I assumed that $x\in X,$ it follows that all elements of $X$ commute with $x,$ in other words, all elements of $X$ belong to $H.$

Answer (score 2):

The subgroup $\left<X\right>$ is equal to all possible finite products of elements of $X$ and their inverses, i.e.
$$\left<X\right> = \{x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2}\cdots x_s^{a_2} : x_i \in G, s \geq 1, a_i = \pm 1\},$$
Note that the $x_i$ need not be distinct. Then just use the fact that the elements of $X$ are pairwise commutative to conclude that $\left<X\right>$ is abelian.

Comment: I have never seen that before. Why finite products and not infinite products? Especially if we don't know whether $X$ is a finite or an infinite subset of $G$?

Comment: Wait a minute, is that that "group word" thingy?

Comment: Infinite products in a group don't make sense.

Comment: @JessyCat You can't multiply an infinite number of group elements. Take the group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ for example. What would $1+1+1+\cdots$ be?

Comment: @EthanAlwaise okay, so I'm figuring that in order for this to be proven rigorously, some kind of induction needs to be used. Now, suppose $x$, $y \in \langle X \rangle$. Do $x$ and $y$ need to be products of the same length? I'm trying to write down a proof by induction, but I'm a little confused as to what that would look like..specifically because I don't know if we can just assume WLOG that the products are of the same length (which would make things easier).

Comment: @arctictern what do you think?

Comment: Nope, can't assume they're the same length (even wlog). Shouldn't be an issue though.

Comment: @arctictern, greeeeat. So is this going to turn into a proof by induction on two different lengths? How does that even work?(I.e., how is that not an issue?)

Comment: (1) Verify the subset Ethan gave is indeed a subgroup (the product of two products-of-things-from-$X\cup X^{-1}$ will again be a product-of-things-from-$X\cup X^{-1}$), (2) Show that if $H\le G$ is any subgroup then it contains $X$ if and only if it contains Ethan's subset.

Comment: @arctictern and then finally show it's Abelian. I was thinking maybe that WLOG, fix the length of $y$ to be $k$, then do induction on the length of $x$?

Comment: It's true that the elements in Ethan's set are formed recursively (take an element in $X$ or $X^{-1}$, multiply it by another, multiply it by another, etc.), but that doesn't mean you'll use induction in the proof. If we take two elements $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_r^{a_r}$ and $x_{r+1}^{a_{r+1}}\cdots x_{r+s}^{a_{r+s}}$ from Ethan's set and multiply them, we get $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_{r+s}^{a_{r+s}}$, which is another element of Ethan's set. Right?

Comment: @arctictern, actually that part - which is that Ethan's set is closed under multiplication - is what I'm finding the most difficult to prove. How do you do that without using induction??

Comment: I just did prove it. Do you not agree that $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_{r+s}^{a_{r+s}}$ would also be an element of Ethan's set?

Comment: @arctictern, yes, you're right. I'm extremely tired, and not thinking as clearly as I should be...